# Permission denied while connecting to the repository using subeclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am trying to connect to a repository location using subeclipse. But every time, I try to connect to the location I get the following error :-

svn: E175002: Permission denied: connect
svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/{repository_location}/'

I have also tried using subversive but that does not seem to work out as well.

**Note**: The repository is at a remote server to which I am connected via VPN. I am able to browse through the repository using the browser and using the same username and password 
that I am using with subeclipse. I am also able to check in and check out the code by using tortoise SVN client. The issue that I am facing is only from within eclipse (i.e. using subeclipse)

Answer (score 1):

Was working under the same conditions (VPN to a office network) when I experienced the same problem. Even though I could browse the repo in the browser, svn plugin gave me 'svn: E175002: Permission denied'. Also had no problems without VPN.

adding

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

to eclipse.ini worked for me